# tkinter: How do I fix my window so that the window doesn't resize when my content resizes?

Tags: python, resize, tkinter, pack

I have a feeling it is to do with my pack() function. The window always "packs" the content in to the smallest size it can possibly be, but because the content is always changing, the window size is always changing and this moves the button, which is centred.

I want the window to stay at a certain size the whole time, e.g. 200x200. The problem is, the window keeps resizing according to how much text is shown, and it makes pushing the button hard because it's always moving.

If you want to see it in action, my code is here: http://pastebin.com/PQWMiqYQ

If someone could please tell me what code I can implement to make the window size constant, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
root.geometry('200x200')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! My game is now complete! :D

Much thanks!